# Digital Speech Decoder

Tags: 14.04

looking for software compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 that will decode digital speech formats from scanners.

http://wiki.radioreference.com/index.php/Digital_Speech_Decoder_(software_package)

Comment: This is not an area I know about, so im not answering but is this what you want http://www.george-smart.co.uk/wiki/Digital_Speech_Decoder